# Is there a way to disable cursor blinking in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

I would like to disable blinking feature of cursor in PyCharm. This setting seem not included in the preferences. I wonder if there are ways to get around that?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if that's tied to your OS settings. In Windows, there's a setting for cursor blinking. You may need to set it globally.

Answer (score 4):

You can disable it by following:

`File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Apperance`

There disable the check box named "Caret Blinking". This affects both the editor cursor and the terminal cursor.

[image]